# There is a problem when I use brace expansion in bash

Tags: bash

There is a problem when I use brace expansion in bash.

I want to get a string of `a b c`, so i use the command of `echo {a..c}`, but i just get a string of `{a..c}`. The operating system I used is CentOS 7.9.

Comment: please share the output of `echo $0` and `which echo`

Comment: ... and output of `echo $-`.

Comment: Could not replicate on ubuntu 20.04, `echo {a..c}` gave the output `a b c`. `echo` is `/usr/bin/echo`

Comment: @squidwardsface it's likely something to do with the shell, the shell's version of echo or the shell's options. will vary by system and config

Comment: `in bash` and are you sure you are running bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable the `braceexpand` option.

`man bash`:

> -B      The shell performs brace expansion (see Brace Expansion above).  This is on by default.

to enable:

```
$ set -o braceexpand # `set -B`
$ echo {a..c}
a b c
```

to disable:

```
$ set +o braceexpand # `set +B`
$ echo {a..c}
{a..c}
```

to get state:

```
$ set -o | grep braceexpand
braceexpand     on
```

```
[[ $- =~ B ]] && echo on || echo off
on
```